# for-loop simplification

Tags: files, for

I would like to understand the for-loop below and perhaps simplify it. 
For example, I'd like to concatenate the rem files for each sample in the directory.

Files:

```
file1.1.fq
file1.rem.1.fq
file1.2.fq
file1.rem.2.fq
file2.1.fq
file2.rem.1.fq
file2.2.fq
file2.rem.2.fq
```

for-loop:

```
list=`for i in *rem*.1.fq; do echo $i | cut -f 1 -d \.; done`
for i in $list; do cat $i.rem.1.fq $i.rem.2.fq > $i.rem.b.fq; done
```

Can I do this without making a list? What does the `cut -f 1 -d` do? And why does `cat $i.rem.1.fq` work but not `cat $i.1.fq` if the the `rem` part of the file name is in between the two `*` on the list? Does that mean it captures everything before `*rem*` (e.g. file1)?

Comment: As a general comment, please note that the "backtick-notation" for command-substitutions is deprecated, and the `$( ... )` notation should be used instead, (i.e. `list="$(for i in ..... done)"` in your example).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
for i in *.rem.1.fq; do
    cat -- "$i" "${i%.1.fq}.2.fq" > "${i%.1.fq}.b.fq"
done
```

Maybe add a check for the existence of files:

```
for i in *.rem.1.fq; do
    if [ -e "${i%.1.fq}.2.fq" ] && [ ! -e "${i%.1.fq}.b.fq" ]; then
        cat -- "$i" "${i%.1.fq}.2.fq" > "${i%.1.fq}.b.fq"
    fi
done
```

---

The method presented in the question is error-prone – if a file contained a space, the second `for` loop might not function correctly.

`cut -f 1 -d.` cuts a string into fields (delimited in this case by `.`), and outputs the requested fields (in this case, just the first). If given the string `file 1.whatever`, it would output `file 1`. Again, this is error prone given the glob pattern `*rem*.1.fq` could return filenames with `anyremthing.1.fq` – the `*` wildcard matches *anything* (including *nothing*).

A better option is to do a single loop and use a parameter expansion, with some form of substitution inside the loop to match other files with relevant names.

- Above, the glob pattern `*.rem.1.fq` is used – you  may wish to narrow this down further – eg. `file[0-9].rem.1.fq`.
- `${param%string}` is used in the loop to remove the suffix `.1.fq`. Many shells also support other forms of parameter expansion substitutions – eg. `${param/string/repl}`.

Also it's generally a good idea to quote all `"$param"` or `"$(command)"` substitutions – otherwise most shells will apply field splitting and filename generation and you might end up trying to `cat file 1` instead of `cat 'file 1'`, for example.

Also don't forget the `--` to mark the end of options if you can't guarantee file names won't start with `-`.